# Use website to communicate with Arduino WirelessProtoShield

Tags: programming

I have a small office with wireless network, is it possible to make a wireless doorbell?
Practical example:
Arduino is connected to the main wireless network and has a static ip,
i have a website that connects through arduino using ftp to activate the "open door" function.
note: "open door" activates a motor to press the button, or i will hack the current doorbell to connect wires :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino wifi web server: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WiFiWebServer just modify the webserver to show a "open" button and to receive a post request and open the door.

Comment: Whilst you link may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the **essential parts of the linked here,** and provide the link for citation. Can you please edit your answer?